# Rails i18n copycopter reaching out to infinity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, i18n-gem, copycopter

I found copycopter a while ago and now started using it. I am pretty happy with it but now am having some weird issues.

My DB size is 8M (thousands of versions on day one) and it keeps adding blubs. It started with a few hundres and over the weekend it went up to 1800+. I did not touch the app over the weekend.

I keep getting blurbs added to the DB nonstop even when I don't edit the application. Things like activerecord.model.x, then activerecord.model.x.other for EVERY MODEL in the app so this is definitely a duplication issue.

I really want to use copycopter but am stuck on this continued blurb adding issue/8M DB. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We have just discovered the same the problem.  It currently seems to be add any form variable into the equation even when there is no copycopter syntax in site.  Also overtime a helper has a label it grabs it.

We narrowed it down to just development ENV, so we think it maybe one of our debugger tools. It seems to capture temp files that are written